# How do I create a user in Amazon Directory Services Simple AD?

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory

I'm using [Amazon Directory Services](http://aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/details/) with a Simple AD instance.  I can join computers to the domain, but I can't figure out how to add users to the domain (and do not see in the documentation whether this is even possible).

How do I create a user in Amazon Simple AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage users (and groups) via a bound instance's Active Directory Users and Computers tool. Details are [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/adminguide/creating_ad_users_and_groups.html).

Note that due to a bug, this must be done from a Windows Server 2008 R2 instance at the time of writing.  Windows Server 2012 is not supported at the time of writing per [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=618788) (registration required).